# Adding up Currency Values in a JavaFX table using BigDecimal

Tags: java, javafx-8, bigdecimal, observablelist

I want to sum the `ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>` values of a JavaFX `TableColumn`. I've used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650158/javafx-tableview-adding-individual-values-in-specific-column) as a reference. The problem is my implementation of it as shown here:

```
private void doSalesTotals() {
olSales.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Sales>() {
  @Override
  public void onChanged(Change<? extends Sales> change) {
    while (change.next()){
      if (change.wasAdded()){
        for (Sales s : change.getAddedSubList()){
          totalWithDiscount.set(totalWithoutDiscount.get().add(s.getAmount()));
          System.out.print(totalWithDiscount);

        }
      } else if (change.wasRemoved()){

      } else if (change.wasReplaced()){

      } else if (change.wasUpdated()){

      }
    }
  }
});
```

keeps giving me a nullpointer exception and no currency addition takes place.

Some context: The table is part of a POS module I'm doing for my 4th year Undergraduate project.

What exactly am I doing wrong and how do I solve it?

Comment: Which line is the exception happening on?

Comment: This line `              totalWithDiscount.set(totalWithoutDiscount.get().add(s.getAmount()));`

Comment: So that could mean one of four things.  Either `s` is null, or `totalWithDiscount` is null, or `totalWithoutDiscount` is null, or `totalWithoutDiscount.get()` is null.  Your debugger will tell you which.

Comment: `System.out.print(s.getAmount())` tells me s.getAmount() is not null.

Comment: So, that leaves three more possibilities.  And please, use the debugger, rather than putting `System.out.println` all over the place.

Comment: kindly take a better look at the question before marking it as a duplicate of something that doesn't help me solve my problem.

Comment: If you follow the advice in the answers to that question, it WILL solve your problem.  Your problem is a null pointer exception.  That question tells you how to deal with null pointer exceptions.  So do my comments here.